# How to save JSON data in a file using writeFileSync?

Tags: javascript, json, iot

I'm working on a home-automation project (IoT) where my websocket server is a subscriber to a MQTT broker. It gets temperature and light intensity data from microcontroller. In a nutshell, the data are saved as JSON data, then I'll have to save the log of all the received data in a file. I used `.writeFileSync()` but it only resulted in `[object Object]` and I have to edit the data.JSON manually before I can run my program because it'll give an error if I don't.

This is the script:

```
var config = require('./data.json');

function writeData() {
    fs.writeFileSync('data.json', config);
}
```

Then I tried changing it into

```
var config = require('./data.json');
let data2 = JSON.stringify(config);
function writeData() {
   fs.writeFileSync('data-2.json', data2);
}
```

but I can't find the file named `data-2.json`.

Please help.

***EDIT***

I've called the writeData() function on this part:

```
    s.on('dev:on', function (id) {
    if (id == 'lamp1') {
        config.lamp1 = true;
    } else if (id == 'fan1') {
        config.fan1 = true;
    }
    client.publish(id, "true");
    writeData();
    console.log('Device ON RECEIVED for ' + id);
});
```

And the rest of the codes which follow are similar to this.

Comment: Not sure how `writeFileSync` works, but `data-2.json` should be in the same folder as the script itself. And _I believe_ the websocket server process should have `write` permission to that folder too.

Comment: You defined `writeData` as a function but forgot to call it.

Comment: @Eimantas thank you. I've tried the script that Sebastian suggested but I can't find data-2.json in the folder...

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
const fs = require('fs');
let config = require('./data.json');

function writeData() {
    fs.writeFileSync('data-2.json', JSON.stringify(config));
}

writeData();
```

Comment: thank you. I've edited my program to this but I'm still unable to find the data-2.json in the same folder as my script.

Comment: If you just run the script above, you should see your data. Just tested it. So the problem might be somewhere else.